# Html5 movie insert into html as a background?

Tags: html, background

Now I have a video(mp4,webm) as background of a html-section. But it does not look good on mobile. I would like place the original html file  into the html code, as background. (I have an animated html5  file whit js) Is it possible? 
Thank you. [enter link description here](https://hirdetestervezes.hu/minta/index2.html#home)

```
<section class="pt-page pt-page-1 section-with-bg section-paddings-0" style="background-image: url(images/home_page_bg_1.jpg);" data-id="home">
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="video-background">
              <source src="images/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="images/moviewebm.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
        </section>
```

Comment: Have you tried resizing it with CSS using @media ?

Comment: no, if I resize the video file, will better on mobile? I think, that html5 were smaller and better. I would like this html file insert somehow:  [link] (http://hirdetestervezes.hu/minta/ujanim/ujanim.html)  But I think, iframe not possible as a background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement different sizes of the video player for different screen sizes using CSS that will fill the screen.

I tested the link and it works fine. Just scale it.